# Размер коллайдера не подстраивается под размер объекта UI

Tags: unity3d, ui

Я хочу иметь облако с текстом внутри и коллайдером, повторяющем форму самого облачка.

Так как текст должен быть внутри облачка, то оно должно быть UI, с компонентом Image.

Я сделал заготовку и создал из нее префаб. Однако, так как заготовка должна лежать и делалась в дочернем объекте, вытянутом по горизонтали, то, когда я сделал из нее префб, он оказался вытянутым по вертикали:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но главная проблема не в этом, а в том, что, когда я переношу это облачко на сцену и хочу его немного уменьшить, то PolygonCollider2D НЕ уменьшается! Я, конечно, могу изменить Size объекта, но мне кажется это не правильный путь. Size должен быть на единице.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать, чтобы при изменении объекта изменялся коллайдер? Он хорошо изменяется, только если это не UI, если не Image, а SpriteRenderer, но мне это не подходит, ведь в облаке должен быть Text!

Comment: Способ только один, DeltaSize соответствует размеру текстуры с учетом pixel per unit. Вот только накой тебе точный коллайдер формы в UI ? Точнее зачем тебе вообще колайдер в UI ? Говорить о правильности совсем не приходится.

Comment: Объясню кратко: игрок будет соединять облака линиями. Для этого использую отдельный объект, который при нажатии выпускает луч в облако. Нужен коллайдер. Но еще облака будут падать друг на друга "мультяшно". Поэтому нужен коллайдер именно такой формы. А почему в UI? Опять же в облаках будет текст (компонент Text). А это UI. Была идея делать отдельно облака и текст, но тогда облака упадут, а текст останется на месте висеть. Есть другой способ получения клика и падения облаков с текстом? Буду рад, если подскажешь, долго уже ищу;)

Comment: Ну всегда можно прикрепить текст к объекту через маленький world space конвас.

Comment: @Yaroslav По канвасу для каждого облака?!?!?

Comment: Да, в чём собственно то проблема? Канвасы рендарятся только по факту изменений контента, а не каждый кадр. Можно.